# uiDraggable revert not working anymore with jquery-2.0.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm want to change from jquery-1.9.1 to jquery-2.0.3 and now the revert for my draggable objects isn't working anymore. I'm using:

```
revert: function(event,ui){
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top: 528, left: 254
            };
            return !event;
        },
```

so the draggable object returns to its original position. The error I'm getting ist:

TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined

top: 528, left: 254

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this in a specific browser or all browsers?

Comment: I've tested Chrome, Firefox and IE10, always the same

Answer (score 0):

add the jquery library.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        };
        return !event;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).data('ui-draggable').originalPosition = {
  top: 50,
  left: 0
};
```